# form submission by using jquery not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

In form submission i am giving action using jquery

Here is my HTML code

```
<form name="frmSearchTops" id="frmSearchTops" method="post" onsubmit="searchitem();">
        <select  name="cboCityNameRes" id="cboCityNameRes">
          <option value=''>City</option>
             {foreach from= $arritemCities item=foo}                      
               {if $smarty.post.hdnCityName eq $foo}                                
                  <option value="{$foo}" selected="selected">{$foo}</option>          
               {else}    
                <option value="{$foo}" {if $foo eq 'City'} selected="selected"{/if}>
                     {$foo}
                </option>
               {/if}    
             {/foreach}    
        </select>
    <select name="cboMaterial" id="cboMaterial">
      <option value="">Material</option>
      <option value="CT">Cotton</option>
      <option value="SL">Silk</option>
    </select>
     <input name="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch"/>       
 </form>
```

Jquery Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function searchitem()
 {
    var strCity = $('#cboCityNameRes').val();
    $("#frmSearchTops").attr("action", "/womens-tops-" + strCity + ".php");
    $("#frmSearchTops").submit();
 }
 </script>
```

Here i am giving action to a dummy link womens-tops-chennai.php. In controller it will redirect to actual page.But for me its not working.Can i submit like this

Comment: Wrap it in `document.ready`

Comment: inside document.ready i can use function

Comment: why document.ready? i dont see reason

Comment: `document.ready` won't make any difference, the event is added inline.

Comment: in form tag no need to specify action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to submit form using `button` type which cannot submit the form, so instead call the function with the onclick event and your script has code to submit the form

```
<input name="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch" onclick='searchitem();'/>
```

### [working demo](http://jsbin.com/obasoj/1/)

Comment: Atleast pls comment for downvoting??

Comment: i want to specify the url where i can give

Answer (score 1):

Change your button to a submit button. You have an input with type `button` which will not submit a form by default. That is why your form doesn't submit.

```
<input name="btnSearch" type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearch"/>
```

With a submit button, you won't need to call `.submit()` because that will happen automatically when your `onsubmit` event handler completes.

Comment: its making some css problem

Comment: A CSS problem? Then perhaps you have some CSS targeting `input[type=button]`?

Comment: yes but to submit a form you need a element with type="submit" the intenet explorer would not send the form if no submit type available

Comment: Then change your CSS to target `input[type=submit]` instead of `input[type=button]`.

Comment: @Athi you can change the CSS to target both types, so it won't affect other pages. Example: `input[type=button], input[type=submit] { background-image: xxx }`